# Any solution for not showing sent mails after sync by imapsync?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, imapsync

I want to sync, my old mail account in gmail to new imap server, but SENT folder on destination is empty.
I tried using imapsync my command:

```
imapsync \
       --user1    user1@example.com \
       --password1 'password1' \
       --host2     newserver.example.com \
       --user2     user2@example.com \
       --password2 'password2' \
       --gmail1 \
       --folderfirst 'SENT' \
       --folderlast 'All'\
       --delete2 \
```

Sent items are in All folder but not showing in SENT. Can you help me?

Comment: Gmail does not have folders. Gmail has labels. All mail is always in the All folder. I think this is why its not working.

Comment: Gmail has folders in IMAP, each label is a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can give me the folder list, as shown by imapsync?

Options --folderfirst needs the exact name, case matters, and the complete path.

All these are different:

```
imapsync ... --folderfirst Sent --folderfirst INBOX.Sent --folderfirst Inbox.Sent
```